# Docker pull so slow

Tags: docker, performance, pull

I had an experience on 2021.09.07: a freshly created docker image is downloaded so slow via docker pull (from hub.docker.com)...
The last layer was the obstacle – it took 40-50 minutes to be finished. What can be the reason?

`e249e58386a8: Downloading [===>    ]  83.73MB/303.3MB`

Comment: How large were the other layers? How fast is your bandwidth measured with the various online speed tests? Was the layer a foreign layer (common on windows images)? Details on exactly what image you were trying to pull will help others debug the last question if you don't know.

Comment: This is a question that only someone with access to Docker Hub's logs on 2021-09-09 could answer in a nonspeculative way. Maybe your particular request happened to be handed to a node with a degraded RAID array. Maybe a cluster node was out for maintenance. Maybe any number of things could be true, but nobody here has any way to prove or disprove any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Docker limits the speeds and amounts of pull requests you can do with a free account. After hitting the limit you need to wait until they reset it. There are several alternative container registries to Docker Hub that you can use instead and that don't suffer so much of the described problem. For example:

- Amazon Elastic Container Registry (ECR): A fully-managed Docker container registry provided by AWS that makes it easy for developers to store, manage, and deploy Docker container images.
- Google Container Registry (GCR): A secure and private registry for Docker container images on Google Cloud Platform.

Answer (score -2):

1. Check your internet connectivity. Specially if you have a proxy or behind firewall. (If firewall has rules, ask admin to whitelist hub.docker.com - this could be the reason)
2. Your PC's firewall, virus-guard etc.
3. Restart the node and check.

Comment: I shall try it next time. But it's strange that all the other layers arrived fine. And this behavior was also on my local laptop and a remote machine. Both showed the same value on X MB/303.3MB.